# Set up tolerance and maximum iteration for Newton's Method

Tags: r, max

How can I set up tolerance (1e-08) and maximum iteration (40) for the following code?

```
newton<-function(fun, grad, x_0) { 
 xold<-x_0 
 xnew<-xold+1000 
 while(1! = 0){ 
    f <- fun(xold) 
    g <- grad(xold) 
    xnew <- xold-f/g 
    cat("xold, xnew, f, g:",xold,' ',xnew,' ',f,' ',g,"\n") 
    if ((1000+xold) == (1000+xnew)) return(xnew) 
    tmp<-readline("go on?") 
    xold<-xnew 
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
newton<-function(fun, grad, x_0,maxiter=40,tol=1e-8) {
 xold<-x_0 
 xnew<-xold+100 # to avoid stopping 
 i<-0 #make counter
 while(i<maxiter){ #do until i=maxiter
    f <- fun(xold) 
    g <- grad(xold) 
    xnew <- xold-f/g 
    cat("xold, xnew, f, g:",xold,' ',xnew,' ',f,' ',g,"\n") 
    #if the absolute difference between old and new value < tol, stop
    if (abs(old-xnew)<tol) return(xnew) 
    tmp<-readline("go on?") 
    xold<-xnew 
    i <- i+1
 } 
}
```

Comment: Can we change "100" to some other numbers? And what does "tmp" stand for?

Comment: You don't actually need the line `xnew<-xold+100` at all, and also `tmp<-readline("go on?")`is pointless here.